# 404 Exception while querying dbpedia

Tags: sparql, jena, dbpedia

I have following code which makes requests to dbpedia server.

```
HttpQuery.urlLimit = 3000;
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString, Syntax.syntaxARQ);
QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(this.endPoint,query);
ResultSet resultSet = qexec.execSelect();
```

The code runs fine, but sometimes raises the following exception.

```
HttpException: 404
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.execGet(HttpQuery.java:349)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.HttpQuery.exec(HttpQuery.java:295)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execResultSetInner(QueryEngineHTTP.java:346)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execSelect(QueryEngineHTTP.java:338)
```

What is the reason for such exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A HTTP 404 is a standard HTTP error that means that the requested resource was not found i.e. the server could not find the service you asked for.

As a public service open to everyone DBPedia is heavily used and often experiences outages for various reasons e.g. maintenance, hardware/software outages, DoS attacks (whether intentional or from unintentionally bad queries)

According to [SPARQL Endpoint Status for DBPedia](http://sparqles.ai.wu.ac.at/endpoint?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fsparql) the endpoint has around 99% availability which means that sometimes it will be unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible reasons.  We don't have enough information to say with certainty which applies here.

As @RobV says, [`HTTP 404`](http://dbpedia.org/resource/HTTP_404) is a standard HTTP error which indicates that the server (which was operational) could not find the resource you asked for -- but we don't know what resources you asked for when you did and didn't get this error, so cannot analyze further.

The `404` does not indicate the server is down, nor that it is refusing to serve you. These conditions (and many others) would result in different [error codes](http://dbpedia.org/resource/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).